# How to append a new data block with new-line in red?

Tags: rebol, red

I tried:

```
data: [a b c]
new-line tail data true
append data [d e f]
```

I get

```
[a b c d e f]
```

not what I expect:

```
[a b c 
d e f]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newline marker is a property of a value slot, not of a series. `new-line tail data true` didn't set this marker, because `tail` of a series does not contain any value slot (but `back tail` does).

```
>> head new-line tail [a b c] on
== [a b c]
>> head new-line back tail [a b c] on
== [a b 
    c
]
>> append [a b c] new-line [d e f] on
== [a b c 
    d e f
]
```